# Using package`regexp` to find all mactch substring in Golang, but get unexpected result

Tags: regex, go

I am using package `regexp` to find all mactch substring in Golang, but get unexpected result.Here is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str := "build: xxxxxx Prefix:middle#6\nPrefix:middle#16026Prefix:middle#1111\n Prefix:middle#110 Prefix:middle.#2 Prefix:middl.e#111 Prefix:middle#112"
    regexpStr := "\\bPrefix:([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\w-.]+[^.])#[0-9]+"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(regexpStr)
    matchs := re.FindAllString(str, -1)
    fmt.Println(matchs)
}
```

You can see it in https://go.dev/play/p/XFSMW09MKxV.

expected:

```
[Prefix:middle#6 Prefix:middle#110 Prefix:middl.e#111 Prefix:middle#112]
```

But I got:

```
[Prefix:middle#6 Prefix:middle#16026 Prefix:middle#110 Prefix:middl.e#111 Prefix:middle#112]
```

Why `Prefix:middle#16026` macthed? Could someone tell me the reason? And how to fix it, thx.

Here is the rules for what should match:

I want to extract `Prefix:${middle}#${number}` in a `String`.

- `${middle}` rules:

  - Allowed characters: letters, numbers, underscores, underscores, dots
  - Must begin with a letter or number
  - Can't end with a dot
- `${number}` rules:

  - Shoule be number
- `Prefix:${middle}#${number}` can appear at the beginning or end of a string, or in the middle of a string, but：

  - Appear at the beginning of the string, it needs to be followed by a space or `/n`;
  - Appear at the end of the string, it needs to be preceded by a space or `/n`;
  - in the middle of the string, but it needs to be preceded and followed by a newline symbol or a space.

Comment: Why _woudn’t_ `Prefix:middle#16026` match?

Comment: What I expect is that `[Prefix:middle#6 Prefix:middle#110 Prefix:middl.e#111 Prefix:middle#112]`，How can I fix it? What kind of `regexpStr` should I use?@Biffen

Comment: Could you explain the rules (in English if not in regex) for what should match? The current pattern matches `Prefix:middle#16026` and I can’t see a reason, or even an intention, for why it shouldn’t.

Comment: @Biffen I update the question to add the rules. Cound you pls read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex with `regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch`:

```
(?:\s|^)(Prefix:[a-zA-Z0-9][\w.-]*[^.]#\d+)(?:\s|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tncITh/4).

**Note** that this pattern will only work after doubling whitespaces in the string because both the whitespace boundaries, `(?:\s|^)` and `(?:\s|$)`, are *consuming* patterns, and will prevent getting consecutive matches. Hence, `regexp.MustCompile(`\s`).ReplaceAllString(str, "$0$0")` or similar should be used before running the above regex.

*Details*:

- `(?:\s|^)` - either a whitespace or start of string
- `(Prefix:[a-zA-Z0-9][\w.-]*[^.]#\d+)` - Group 1:

  - `Prefix:` - a fixed string
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - an alphanumeric
  - `[\w.-]*` - zero or more letters, digits, underscores, dots or hyphens
  - `[^.]` - a char other than `.`
  - `#` - a `#` char
  - `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\s|$)` - either a whitespace or end of string

See the [Go demo](https://go.dev/play/p/Fklr4SSWQ-T):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str := "Prefix:middle#113 build: xxxxxx Prefix:middle#6\nPrefix:middle#16026Prefix:middle#1111\n Prefix:middle#110 Prefix:middle.#2 Prefix:middl.e#111 Prefix:middle#112"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?:\s|^)(Prefix:[a-zA-Z0-9][\w.-]*[^.]#\d+)(?:\s|$)`)
    matchs := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(regexp.MustCompile(`\s`).ReplaceAllString(str, "$0$0"), -1)
    for _, m := range matchs {
        fmt.Println(m[1])
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Prefix:middle#113
Prefix:middle#6
Prefix:middle#110
Prefix:middl.e#111
Prefix:middle#112
```

Comment: Thx for response quickly! I update the question to add the rules. Cound you pls read it again?

Comment: @spike014 What does not work? What do you expect?

Comment: I comment in the end of the code, https://go.dev/play/p/lPZAjMyGIHH

Comment: @spike014 See the update.

Comment: Appear at the beginning of the string, I want it to be followed by a space or `/n`;

Comment: @spike014 Then how can you expect `Prefix:middle#113` to match?

Comment: When `Prefix:middle#113` appears at the beginning of the string, and it is followed by a space or `/n`. `Prefix:middle#113` matched. Can this be implemented by regex?

Comment: @spike014 Yes, but you will need to repeat a part of the regex.

Comment: Wow! But when `Prefix:middle#113` appears at the end of the string, it needs to be preceded by a space or `/n` Can this be implemented by regex in Golang too?

Comment: @spike014 I see that the whitespace must be doubled for all these updates to work. Otherwise, you won't get consecutive matches.

Comment: @spike014 See [this Go demo](https://go.dev/play/p/5SpcyDgLqoi), does it work as expected?

Comment: OMG! It works os well. Cound you please update your answer, and explain how it works as you can? Thank you so much again.